# Dataset convert to string array

Tags: c#-4.0, dataset

Dears

I got data Dataset, but I want to convert to String array.
Here is my code, using C#
How do I fix?

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(
                "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source="
                + XLS_FILE_NAME_AND_PATH_HERE
                + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;");

            StringBuilder stbQuery = new StringBuilder();
            stbQuery.Append("SELECT * FROM [" + SHEETNAME_HERE + "$1:1]");
            OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(stbQuery.ToString(), con);`enter code here`

            DataSet dsXLS = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(dsXLS);
```